# OS X (10.6) Apache Sudden Death, Nginx not working either

Tags: apache-2.2, mac-osx, nginx, operating-system

I turned on my computer today and apache wasn't working. This is weird as its been working for the last 6 months without issue.

The only thing I did which may of caused a problem, is I uninstalled a bunch of gems. This shouldn't be the issue though as apache doesn't rely on gems.

I decided to give nginx a try to see if it would work and have the exact same issue.

The symtoms are:

- I go to http://localhost and get the browsers default 404 page (not rendered by apache/nginx)
- No error is found anywhere (I checked all logs)
- Apache is rinning (also tried with Nginx)

How can I debug this to find the root of the problem? I can't think of why this would be happening.

I've tried repairing permissions in case this was the issue, apparently it wasn't. Everything was working the other day, and nothing changed in the apache config.

**Update:**
Here is the output of `telnet localhost 80`

```
$ telnet localhost 80
Trying ::1...
telnet: connect to address ::1: Connection refused
Trying fe80::1...
telnet: connect to address fe80::1: Connection refused
Trying 127.0.0.1...
telnet: connect to address 127.0.0.1: Connection refused
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host
```

Comment: What directory is apache supposed to load pages etc from? Is that directory still there?

Comment: Yes, the server root is just /usr as I'm using passenger to load rails apps. Apache config all looks good.

Comment: I would normally get "It works!" when visiting localhost/ and get a failed to connect error instead (issued by the browser).

Comment: If you telnet to port 80 does it connect?  Also, are you using the built-in OSX Apache or did you compile it by hand?

Comment: I've updated my post to include the output of "telnet localhost 80". Its not connecting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://hintsforums.macworld.com/showthread.php?t=83942

`sudo apachectl -t` reviled apache couldn't find the passenger gem, which makes sense as I was messing with the gems in `rvm ree@global` gemset.

The solution was to reinstall the passenger gem with:

```
$ rvm ree@global
$ gem install passenger
```

and restart apache.